# Keep cropping image to div width, till window is scaled below certain width, then make the remaining portion of the image act responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN MOVED HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419005/crop-image-down-when-scaling-browser-window-to-given-browser-window-width-then)

When scaling the browserwindow I want to the image to crop till the browserwindow reaches a certain width, then I want the image to become responsive maintaining its cropped state. In the example you can see that the image loses its cropped state when the window reaches 800 px, It does become responsive, but I need it do this in the cropped state that it has when reaching 800 px.

```css
#apple-box {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      #big-apple {
        width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="apple-box">
  <img id="big-apple" src="http://www.stedentripidee.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stedentrip-new-york.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to `cover` in order to crop the image.

```css
#apple-box {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* to center the div */
}

#big-apple {
  height: 482px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #big-apple {
    height: auto;
    object-fit: fill;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="apple-box">
  <img id="big-apple" src="http://www.stedentripidee.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stedentrip-new-york.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your comment! However, the image does not continue as responsive in its cropped state (as cropped at window size 800px) but uses the whole image in responsive mode.

Comment: Once the window reaches 800 px wide, the image should become responsive and continue in its cropped state in doing so. But it now jumps to its whole image when the window reaches 800px wide.