# Crop image down when scaling browser-window to given browser-window width. Then let remaining portion of image be responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the code below to attempt the following:

1. As the browser-window is scaled down, the image is cropped till the
   browser-window is scaled down to width 800px or less.
2. At Browser-window width 800 px or less, the image should become
   responsive. Meaning: that part of the photo that's left remaining
   (after being cropped by scaling the browser-window) should scale
   along with the browser-window.

But it's not working. At the moment, while using the code below, the image does crop, and when browser-window width 800px or less is reached the image does become responsive, but only by loading back the complete and uncropped image to do so. I want the cropped portion of photo to become responsive.

Can anyone help please? Also a [**JSFIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/shvaqk9v/).

```css
#apple-box {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      #big-apple {
        width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="apple-box">
  <img id="big-apple" src="http://www.stedentripidee.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stedentrip-new-york.png">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried replacing 100vw with 100%?

Comment: Just tried that. Responds the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you want to achieve? [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shvaqk9v/3/)

```
 #apple-box {
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://www.stedentripidee.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stedentrip-new-york.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 400px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      #apple-box:after {
        content: '';
        display:block;
        padding: 28.5%;
      }
    #apple-box{
        height: auto;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I mean. Is there also a way to do this without the image needing to be a background-image?

Comment: An upvote is much appreciated. Ill figure it out for u.

Comment: Any luck yet, Ron?

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the Image as a background-Image in css. That gives you more control and is less coding and nesting.

Here the code:

```css
#apple-box {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://www.stedentripidee.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stedentrip-new-york.png");
  background-size: 125%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<div id="apple-box">
</div>
```